# How do I write a sed or a awk command that finds a pattern and deletes it in a text file

Tags: awk, sed

I have the following lines in a text file:

```
docker pull ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/{REPOSITORY}/{IMAGE_NAME}:FOO.${TAG_NAME}
docker pull ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/{REPOSITORY}/{IMAGE_NAME}:BAR.${TAG_NAME}
docker pull ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/{REPOSITORY}/{IMAGE_NAME}:BAZ.${TAG_NAME}
```

I want to write a `sed` or `awk` command that finds all occurrences of `FOO.`, `BAR.` and `BAZ.` in the above lines in a file and deletes these occurrences so that the result looks like this in the end:

```
docker pull ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/{REPOSITORY}/{IMAGE_NAME}:${TAG_NAME}
docker pull ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/{REPOSITORY}/{IMAGE_NAME}:${TAG_NAME}
docker pull ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/{REPOSITORY}/{IMAGE_NAME}:${TAG_NAME}
```

Comment: While your description says that you want to replace `FOO`, your sample output says that you want to replace `FOO.`.

Comment: and your comments imply you don't want to find `FOO` at all, instead you want to find and replace whatever is in the position that `FOO` currently occupies in your sample input. So what is it you **really** want to find/replace - whatever text is between `:` and `$` or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to replace to first occurance of `:something.` in every line, test

```
sed 's/:[^.]*[.]/:/' inputfile
```

When this works and you want it replaced in the file without making a backup, you can use the option `-i`:

```
sed -i 's/:[^.]*[.]/:/' inputfile
```

When `${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/{REPOSITORY}/{IMAGE_NAME}` might have a `:`, the pattern is matched at the wrong place. When you are sure that the `${TAG_NAME}` is without `:`, use

```
sed -r 's/:[^.]*[.]([^:]*)$/:\1/' inputfile
```

Edit: After the comment of @potong, I replaced '.' with ':' in the replacement strings. I kept the wrong character.

Comment: Perhaps the replacement should be `:` not `.`?

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question with the clear explanation. I had to tweak the regex a little bit to fully suit my requirement though.

Comment: @potong that's right. Here's what worked for me `sed -ir 's/:[^.]*[A-Z][.]/:/' release.sh`

Answer (score 4):

Sed one:

```
sed 's/\b\(FOO\|BAR\|BAZ\)\.//' input_file
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question. Is there a generic way to achieve this, through a regex perhaps?

Comment: What do you mean by generic? Do you have problems running this? This sed command already uses regex. That's almost all sed does anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of these Perl one-liners:

```
# Remove { FOO, BAR or BAZ } and the following '.' :
perl -pe 's/(FOO|BAR|BAZ)[.]//' in_file > out_file

# Remove *anything* between the last ':' (exclusive) and '.' (inclusive) :
perl -pe 's/\A(.+:)[^.]+[.]/$1/' in_file > out_file
```

The Perl one-liners use these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.

The regex uses:
`\A` : beginning of the line,
`(.+:)` : capture into variable `$1` everything between the first character and the first semicolon,
`[^.]+[.]` : 1 or more occurrence of any character other than '`.`', followed by '`.`'. It is surrounded by brackets to match a literal dot: `[.]`

**SEE ALSO:**

[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for taking the time to answer! I've tried to run the same regex using sed but it doesn't work. Do you happen to know a sed or an awk equivalent of the above command?

Answer (score 0):

In awk the variable **FS containing a regex** can help.

```
$ cat file

docker pull ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/{REPOSITORY}/{IMAGE_NAME}:FOO.${TAG_NAME}
docker pull ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/{REPOSITORY}/{IMAGE_NAME}:BAR.${TAG_NAME}
docker pull ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/{REPOSITORY}/{IMAGE_NAME}:BAZ.${TAG_NAME}
```

In the input, we can see that the 3 words, each one with 3 characters (FOO, BAR, BAZ) and followed by dot. We can make a regex for the match inside the FS separator...

```
FS='[A-Z]{3}\\.'
```

In the awk manual we can read that "the value of FS may be a string containing any regular expression. In this case, each match in the record for the regular expression separates fields."
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Field-Splitting.html

So we have

```
awk -v FS='[A-Z]{3}\\.' '{print $1 $2}'  file

docker pull ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/{REPOSITORY}/{IMAGE_NAME}:${TAG_NAME}
docker pull ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/{REPOSITORY}/{IMAGE_NAME}:${TAG_NAME}
docker pull ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/{REPOSITORY}/{IMAGE_NAME}:${TAG_NAME}
```

..without comma: `$1 $2`

The same result gives the regex with the 3 specific words:

```
$ awk -v FS='(FOO|BAR|BAZ)\\.' '{print $1 $2}'  file
docker pull ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/{REPOSITORY}/{IMAGE_NAME}:${TAG_NAME}
docker pull ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/{REPOSITORY}/{IMAGE_NAME}:${TAG_NAME}
docker pull ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/{REPOSITORY}/{IMAGE_NAME}:${TAG_NAME}
```

--

Comment: This solution worked quite well in my case but it was affecting other lines that are in my text file. Nevertheless, I'm grateful to you for taking the time to answer my question concisely :)